# Apply multiple functions over spark window rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My understanding of spark windows is as follows:

```
current row (1) -> window rows (1 or more) -> aggregation func. -> output for the current row (1)
```

where a single row can be included in multiple windows. The aggregation function `f` is called with `f.over(window)`, which limits the window scope to only a single function. For example, I cannot apply `filter()`, especially not a dynamic one, on only window rows before aggregating with `sum().ower(window)`.

To do custom processing of the window rows, I can:
a) write UDF which gets window rows as input
b) use collect_list() to get window rows as a list for each row and continue processing on these lists

Is there any other option to use multiple standard spark functions on the same window rows?

Answer (score 1):

The filter usecase can be achieved by applying `sum` over a `conditional` expression. It's possible to use multiple spark functions over the same window. For example, the below spark snippet is a valid.

```py
(df.withColumn("a", f.sum().over(window))
   .withColumn("b", f.first().over(window))
)
```

If you are looking to apply custom functions then you can write User Defined Aggregate Function ([`UDAF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html)) using Scala or Java. In your only option is python then `collect_list` and `UDF` is the way to go.